# Were "meridiem" and "mediam diem" in free variation in Latin?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Both "meridiem" and "mediam diem" seem to have carried both the meaning "midday" and "(the) south" in Latin, if their Romance descendants are any indication.

From "meridiem", we get apparently Italian "meriggio" and Portuguese "meridio" (and English "meridian").

From "mediam diem", we get apparently Italian "mezzodi" and Portuguese "meio-dia".

Were there any differences in usage between "meridiem" and "mediam diem"? Was one more formal and one less? How did they come to be in competition?

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8912/telling-time-in-latin

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that any of these is 'in competition'. There are differences, as you suspect, but it's not too difficult to understand them.

*meridies* is used in the same way as English 'noon', or French 'midi', i.e. the single point in time.

Less precisely, an interval of time at the middle of the day is *meridianum tempus*.

*ad mediam diem* means 'towards the middle of the day' — by which the approach of either of the two previous alternatives is indicated.

Comment: so would your suggestion be that in classical Latin, mediam diem appeared as part of phrases like ad mediam diem, and only in later Latin became lexicalized and conflated in meaning to meridiem?

Comment: @Colin  I can't really speak about later Latin, but _meridies_ is certainly classical, and supposedly is conflated from _merus_ (pure) rather than _medius/-a_ and _dies_.

Comment: I think meridies is a dissimilation of medidies (at least that's what wiktionary says).

Comment: It's just one of those instances where it would be nice to know the derivation, but in which we can't ever be certain.

Comment: tempus is neuter.

Comment: @TomCotton wiktionary seems to imply "medidies" is an attested form. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/medidies . The etymology from pure + day has the hallmark of a folk etymology.

Comment: @TomCotton. Wkipedia is a treasure house of nonsense. Here is gives a cross reference to L/S, which in turn refers to "meridies", which in turn says that this is "for medidies from medius-dies", in other words an etymology. The reference to Gauthiot is even more elusive.

Comment: @fdb It's neuter now — thanks! I'm quite satisfied with the etymology in L/S, but I'm quite relaxed about it and don't find it necessary to know for sure.

Comment: @Colin Yes, I agree that a derivation from _merus_ is probably nonsense (I did say _supposedly_!).